# Span of a function that just iterates through a sequence?

Tags: algorithm

I am confused about how to calculate the span and work of an algorithm. If an algorithm just iterates through a series of items, how would I know the span?

Answer (score 0):

From [this link](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse332/17wi/lectures/forkjoin-2/Z-inked-b.pdf) we can see that

1. The **span** of an algorithm is how long it would take if it were as parallel as possible, and
2. The **work** of an algorithm is how long it would take if it were fully sequential.

For the span, note that some algorithms can be divided into parts. For example, if I were writing an algorithm to compute **z**, a product of two values **x** and **y** where **x** and **y** satisfy the following:

1. Neither the computation of **x** nor the computation of **y** can be parallelized;
2. Both **x** and **y** take the same amount of time to compute;
3. The computation of **x** and **y** is the significant step in the computation of **z**

then calculating **z** by computing **x** and **y** in parallel would take half as long as if we just computed their values serially. In this case, the span would be equal to half of the work for this algorithm.

You can also follow the link for more examples.